# Why does std::bind demand a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, std, bind, ref

I implemented some class without a copy constructor:

```
class SomeClass{
public:
    SomeClass() = default;
    SomeClass(const SomeClass&) = delete;
    SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass&) = delete;
};
```

In addition, I have a **function** which will be the std::bind argument:

```
void function(SomeClass& object){
    //some code...
}
```

In the main( ) function I create **x** variable of type SomeClass, with which I can change the signature of the **function** to void ( ):

```
int main() {    
   SomeClass x;
   auto newFunc = std::bind(function,x);
}
```

The question is - Why doesn't it work?
i.e. Why does std::bind need the copy constructor?
If I changed it to :

```
 int main() {       
       SomeClass x;
       auto newFunc = std::bind(function,std::ref(x));
    }
```

It would work.

Comment: Just general advice: avoid `std::bind`, prefer a lambda in its place.

Comment: From [this `std::bind` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (more specifically [the notes section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Notes)): "The arguments to bind are **copied or moved**, and are never passed by reference unless wrapped in [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) or [`std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/cref)." (Emphasis by me)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , thank you, I got it :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: If there isn’t a duplicate, isn’t that an answer?